# Where in the registry are the Windows logo keys set?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'd like to change the application which runs when I hit the Windows logo-F key from the default desktop search, to a different application, and I'd like to do it within the registry, not with an additional application running in the background.

I've been searching on this subject for a while now.  I've found AutoHotKey but it operates by running in the background.  What I'm looking for is a registry setting that will allow me to change Win-F to run a different application.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: What makes you think it is the registry, and not hard coded in `explorer.exe` or something?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/41486/the-windows-registry-why-and-where-does-it-exist?rq=1

Comment: Actually, I don't know it for a fact.  I'm hoping that's the case (and isn't hardcoded).  Considering that every other little granular detail is an option in the Registry, I'm hoping that's the case with the Windows logo key mappings as well.